# Class.getSimpleName NPE with GIN, GWT 2.5

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-gin

I read somewhere that GWT 2.5 now allows Class.getSimpleName.

I am using GWT 2.5, GXT 3.x.

This gave me GIN injector NPE:

```
GWT.log(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + commentString);
```

Is getting the error due to

- The gin.jar version I am using may not be up-to-par with GWT 2.5
- GIN does not support all features of GWT 2.5;
- I have read wrongly, GWT does not yet support Class.getSimpleName.
- Some other reason
  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes..I too read the same and in a blind room some days.But the fact is the **commit is still pending**

@Daniel Kurka recently `abonded` the code  https://gwt-review.googlesource.com/#/c/2220/

if you want you can super source from here

https://gwt-review.googlesource.com/#/c/2220/4/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/Class.java

or

as @Andrea commented  we have to wait for sdk 2.6 :)

Comment: Actually the commit has been submitted, and it is currently available on [master](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/9539881186aef4f01b61fbcf45259b85b4ec6dfb). It is marked as abandoned (as any other change-id so far) because every commit on gerrit is (still) 'pushed' directly to the SVN repo on google code.

Comment: thanks andrea for update from which version its going to be effect ??

Comment: I'd say [2.6](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3404).